# Issue in connecting Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

While connecting to SQL Server 2005, I am getting the following error.

> "An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (Provider: Named Pipes Provider,
>   error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 2)"

I restarted the Server and then tried to connect to SQL Server, it is allowing me to connect. Whenever the problem comes, I am restarting the server. But I want the actual solution for this problem.

Can anybody help me out in solving this issue.

Comment: What do the logs say at the point of trying to connect, and when you lose connection?

Comment: I just found that it was  needed to start all Services . Thanks For your approach